# Some dwarf stays outside ignoring all my "commands"

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I recently started a new fortress. My Mason (a valuable dwarf) is just standing outside during snow storms and stuff with "No job". He doesn't eat and drink.

I tried different stuff to get him back:

- Switched off all his labors (thought he would stuck in a job or somewhat)
- Made a burrow and called all civilians into it
- switched back on his labors (tried to get him a job)
- He could get inside (other dwarfs do so, too)
- He hasn't any injuiry (exception: hungry and thirsty from standing outside :/ ) 
  and hes capable to walk.

Long story short, he died of thirst. But now my expedition leader standing outside too.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: did you try making a meeting hall zone, or a sculpture garden/zoo? That's a good way to gather all your idle dwarves.

Comment: good point. i got both. But the dwarfs outside dont care about it. I also removed the caravan. No reaction :/

Comment: how about putting him in the military and giving him some orders?

Comment: mhpf. My expedition leader died, too. Cant check your hint anymore.

Comment: Ah. My dwarfes got a "geology" problem. Accidiently removed the downward stairs by removing ramps :/ The "get inside" thing happend before that... 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did he get stuck outside during the snowstorm or before?

Comment: @noqqe Post that as an answer to your question and accept it.

Comment: @Paralytic he gets stuck before the snowstorm. There was no connection to the weather anyways.

at Pubby i cant. i have to wait 4 hours to answer to my own question. What a "great" idea from stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

You must make sure your outside Dwarves are able to enter the fort again. You could check if the "outside" is accessible by building something outside, if it tells you that there isn't material available, your problem is there. You can even track where the problem is using this by moving the cursor along the route you think your Dwarves should be able to access.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your dwarves are mildly injured in brawls, it can be as superficial as a bruised thigh, and they'll lie down and refuse to work until taken to some medical area. Aside from that I have *no* idea.

Comment: You should try to avoid posting inconclusive answers on this site.